# Django - Redirect only after closing the javascript modal manually

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a comment form in Django, and after submiting the comment, there's this modal popup that displays some text, but it is appearing only for a few seconds until the page redirects. But I want the modal to be there until I manually click on the "cross" button (or anywhere outside of the modal box), and then the page should redirect to the location as specified.

views.py:

```
def add_comment_to_project(request,pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('project_detail', pk=pk) //here it redirects.
else:
    form=CommentForm()
return render(request, 'portfolio/add_comment_to_project.html', {'form':form})
```

add_comment_to_project.html:

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Comment</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="project-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button id="myBtn" type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </form>

<!-- the Modal (prompt after clicking the send button) -->
    <div id="mymodal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal Content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Thank you for your response ! :).<br>It has been recorded. It will be displayed once it has been approved by the author.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('mymodal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block"; //as initially, the display is none.
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    event.preventdefault();
    /*window.location.reload();*/
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

I searched a lot for the same but couldn't find a relevant answer for how to achieve this in Django.

I want it to be redirected to "Project_detail.html" only after the modal is closed manually, and not just directly after submitting the comment. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submit button:

```
<button id="myBtn" type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Send</button>
```

you should implement a button or a link which will only trigger modal window:

```
<a class="send_comment">Send comment</a>
```

After that in js you should pop up the modal and send post when close button in modal is clicked:

```
function send_comment_modal() {
        $(".send_comment").click(function() {
            $('.modal')
              .modal('show')
            ;
        });

        $('.modal .submit').click(function() {    
            $.post(window.location.href, temp, function(result){
                if(result.success == 'ok') {
                    return;
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

I didn't test the code but I think you can get the idea behind my snippet!

Comment: I have understood the logic behind your code, but as its jQuery in your snippet, and as I am not much familiar with it, could you please comment your snippet and explain whats exactly happening? mainly the second part starting from `$.post(window...)`. thanks

Comment: as I wrote, when you click on the link the modal window pops up. When you click on the button in the modal window it sends post request. However, my piece of code doesn't include the context (temp variable) which you should probably also pass with post request.